# I'm having trouble traversing a newly appended DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have a form that I want to be used to add entries.  Once an entry is added, the original form should be reset to prepare it for the next entry, and the saved form should be duplicated prior to resetting and appended onto a div for 'storedEntries.'  This much is working (for the most part), but Im having trouble accessing the newly created form... I need to change the value attribute of the submit button from 'add' to 'edit' so properly communicate what clicking that button should do.  heres my form:

```
  <div class="newTruck">
    <form id="addNewTruck" class='updateschedule' action="javascript:sub(sTime.value, eTime.value, lat.value, lng.value, street.value);">

        <b style="color:green;">Opening at: </b>
            <input id="sTime" name="sTime" title="Opening time" value="Click to set opening time" class="datetimepicker"/>

        <b style="color:red;">Closing at: </b>
            <input id="eTime" name= "eTime" title="Closing time" value="Click to set closing time" class="datetimepicker"/>

        <label for='street'>Address</label>
            <input type='text' name='street' id='street' class='text' autocomplete='off'/>
            <input id='submit' class='submit' style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" type="submit" value='Add new stop'/>
        <div id='suggests' class='auto_complete' style='display:none'></div>
            <input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat'/>
            <input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng'/>

  </form>

 </div>
```

ive tried using a hundred different selectors with jquery to no avail... heres my script as it stands:

```
function cloneAndClear(){
    var id = name+now;
    $j("#addNewTruck").clone(true).attr("id",id).appendTo(".scheduledTrucks");
    $j('#'+id).filter('#submit').attr('value', 'Edit');

    $j("#addNewTruck")[0].reset();

    createPickers();
}
```

the element is properly cloned and inserted into the div, but i cant find a way to access this element... the third line in the script never works.

Another problem i am having is that the 'values' in the cloned form revert back to the value in the source of the html rather than what the user inputs.

advice on how to solve either of these issues is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're doing with that third line of code. What's the intent?

Comment: Also, what are the values for the variables 'name' and 'now'?

Comment: The intent of the third line is to change the value of the input button from "add new truck" to "edit."  i was able to do this by changing the first line to:

$j("#addNewTruck").clone(true).attr("id",id).appendTo(".scheduledTrucks").children('#submit').attr('value','Edit')

'now' is current the time (new Date()), and 'name' is now a basic string of text, which is just a placeholder for the user account name that i will be replacing it with in the jsp

Comment: after hours of trying to figure it out, i was somehow able to get it the minute after i posted with the method described above.  however, your suggestion (find(':submit').val('Edit');) worked too.  I am still having trouble with the second problem i mentioned, however

Comment: what appears to be happening with the second problem is that the javascript in the action attribute, sub(sTime.value, eTime.value, lat.value, lng.value, street.value), is passing the arguments of the first form, whose values have already been reset.  i thought that even though the id's non-unique once a new entry is made, the browser would know to pass the values of the tags contained within the form.  this doesnt appear to be the case.

im trying to figure out a way to pass the values from the correct form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `find` not `filter`

```
$j('#'+id).find('#submit')
```

That should work in practice, though you've got problems there because there are multiple elements with the same id. I'd change your HTML to use classes, or in this specific case, you don't need either:

```
$j('#' + id).find(":submit")
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `.val()`? and instead of `.filter()`, use `.find()`

```
$j('#'+id).find(':submit').val('Edit');
```

Answer (score 0):

nickf solution works. (just wrote a piece of code to check that). Do check the definition of filter in jquery documentation.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

You have use find in this case. Also as nick mentioned having multiple elements with same id is troublesome, especially when you are doing dom manipulation. Better go with appropriate classes.